# onListItemClick not called in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a ListFragment which contains a list however onListItemClick is never called.  I am not using getListView() which I suspect is the problem.  I am pulling my list view from the xml as such:

```
    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

And then setting the adapter like this:

```
    list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.title, mCursor, new String[]{"title"},  new int[]{R.id.my_title}) );
```

Since I need to set the adapter on the list, I do not use setListAdapter() either.  Is it not possible to pull the list from the xml and use onListItemClick?  I would like to keep my list view in the xml so I do not have to set all of the properties programmatically.

If this is not possible, how can I select items in my list?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me why you aren't using the standard pattern.  call setListAdapter on the ListFragment, passing it your Customadapter.  You can do that and still define the list in a layout by inflating it in newView.  You're probably bypassing some code by not calling setListAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  Try this answer.  Keep your layout file as it is.  Override the following method in your FragmentList class:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Make sure that your layout define a ListView with the right id, as follows:

```
 <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Then, just call FragmentList::setListAdapter:

```
setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.title, mCursor, new String[]{"title"},  new int[]{R.id.my_title}) );
```

Should work, ticky-boo.

Comment: It doesnt look like I can override newView within ListFragment.  I can from within my CustomAdapter since it extends SimpleCursorAdapter, however, I don't believe that's the proper place for it.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  I grabbed code from the wrong place.  The approach is the same but override onCreateView.

Comment: Thanks.  Not having onCreateView is what was causing the list from the xml to not be shown.